# how to send multiple jquery object throughout .html()?

Tags: jquery, html, object

When I use jquery .html(), i know i can send jquery object using it but when I send multiple object, then the output becomes "[object Object]". I did some workarounds but couldn't resolve the issue..

here is script

```
    $('.kim2').on('click', function(){
        var ok = $(this).next();
        var trunk = "hmm";
        console.log(ok);
        $('#content').html(function(){
            return ok + trunk;
        });
    });
```

html :

```
            <div class="kim2">피의자 상황</div>
              <div id="b"class="kim2b">
                <div id="b1" class="kim2bb">부양가족 <br />과도한 곤경</div>
                <div id="b2" class="kim2bb">건강상태 매우 <br />나쁨</div>
                <div id="b3" class="kim2bb">고령</div>
                <div id="b4" class="kim2bb">사회적<br /> 유대관계 분명</div>
                <div id="b5" class="kim2bb">사회적 <br />유대관계 결여</div>
                <div id="b6" class="kim2bb">약물중독 <br />알코올 중독</div>
                <div id="b7" class="kim2bb">해당없음</div>
              </div>
```

when I remove trunk from return sentence , it's perfectly working but when i add some other object it becomes as mentioned above.

I want to send as many objects as i want with some variation. How?

Comment: `ok + trunk;` is the same of `ok.toString() + trunk`, that's why it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to concatenate two objects as strings. They're not strings, so that won't work without converting them to strings first.

The best way to do this is actually to use jQuery functions to [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) any existing contents, and then [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) each of the two objects to your container.

Like this:

```
    $('#content').empty().append(ok, trunk);
```

or even:

```
    $('#content').empty().append(ok, "hmm");
```

---

One potential problem that you may run into when using this, is that the `#b` div is removed from it's original position and **moved** into the content instead of **copied**.

The problem here is that if the element you're appending is already in the DOM, it will be moved into the new location, rather than copied. From the docs:

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):

To fix this, you need to [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the object yourself, and append the clone rather than the original object:

```
$('.kim2').on('click', function(){
    var okCopy = $(this).next().clone();
    console.log(okCopy);
    $('#content').empty().append(okCopy, "hmm");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#content').html(ok.html() + trunk);
```

if you need the ok outer HTML then use:

```
$('#content').html(ok[0].outerHTML + trunk);
```

Comment: `ok.html()` does not include the `ok` object itself, just its contents. You could wrap it in a `<div>` first, and then get the contents of that - but that's needlessly convoluted.